# How do I convert a lead in SFDC through API using Restforce Gem

Tags: ruby, salesforce, restforce

I've been using the Restforce gem with Ruby (sans Rails) in order to add leads, contacts, and opps to Salesforce. Now I want to be able to convert a lead to a contact or account. Here is SFDC's documentation on the method I'd like to use.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_convertlead.htm

However, Restforce does not appear to support this feature yet. There is no convert_lead or convertLead method with that library. I'd appreciate pointers on how I could work around this or get Restforce to work for me? Thanks!

Comment: It appears that's SOAP API rather than REST, you're going to have to follow something along this guide https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000B3dSIAS to create your own rest class and then you should be able to use that.

Answer (score -1):

Clone the Restforce gem on Github and add `convertLead` method to `restforce/api.rb`. There are plenty of examples within that file.